# Change (or) Alter scope of a function, within the function in javascript

Tags: javascript

As the question says,

I want to know that if there a way to change scope of a function like this,

```
function foo(){
    var t = this;
    log(t);//{bar:'baz'}
    /*** Do something over here to change the scope ***/
    var newThis = this;
    log(newThis); //{something:'somethingelse'}
}
```

I am just curious to know, if there is a way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function foo(){
    log(this);
    /*** Do something over here to change the scope ***/
    with (newThis) {
        log(this);
    }
}
```

I wouldn't recommend using it though.

> Using with is not recommended, and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5 strict
>   mode. The recommended alternative is to assign the object whose
>   properties you want to access to a temporary variable.

https://developer.mozilla.org/index.php?title=En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/With